# getKeyFrame method accepts a float that is continuously incrementing. Why?

Tags: animation, libgdx

I am following a libgdx book. In it, the author uses Animation class to play an animation. This is the relevant code:

```
public class Flappee{

private float animationTimer = 0;

private static final float FRAME_DURATION=0.25f;

public Flappee(Texture texture){

    TextureRegion[][] flappeeTextures = new TextureRegion(texture).split(118,118);
    collisionCircle = new Circle(x,y,COLLISION_RADIUS);
    this.animation = new Animation(FRAME_DURATION,flappeeTextures[0][0],flappeeTextures[0][1]);
    animation.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
}

public void update(float delta){
        animationTimer+=delta; //called in render method of ScreenAdapter class
}


public void draw(SpriteBatch batch){
        TextureRegion texture = animation.getKeyFrame(animationTimer);
        batch.draw(//drawing commands);
    }
}
```

I don't understand why animationTimer needs to be incremented every render loop. As you can see it is crucial to `getKeyFrame` to return the right textureRegion. I guess it has something to do with looping the same animation all the time. May I ask for additional explanation on this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delta value passed to render is the amount of time since the last frame, so by adding it to `animationTimer` each time render is called means that `animationTimer` holds the amount of time since the animation started running.

This is needed to work out what frame to display at any given time. So if you wanted your animation to run at 5 frames per second, and `animationTimer` was 400ms, then it can work out that it should display frame numer 2.

It doesn't simply pick the next frame each time render is called because that would tie the animation speed to the framerate, which is not always desirable. Also framrates are not constant so this approach ensures any inconsistencies are smoothed out.